# Convert list of strings into list of lists with each element in list of lists as each iterable letter in string. All in one line

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

With list of strings x:

```
x = ['foo', 'bar']
```

How can I do the following in one line?

```
y = []
for word in x:
    y.append([n for n in word])
print y
```

Resulting in:

```
[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `list` and simple list comprehension:

```
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> y = [list(word) for word in x]
>>> y
[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]
```

or by using `map` with `list`:

```
>>> y = map(list, x)
>>> y
[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `list` from each string within a list comprehension.

```
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> [list(i) for i in x]
[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> map(list, ['foo', 'bar'])
[['f', 'o', 'o'], ['b', 'a', 'r']]
```